# Laravel chat app : Unable to deliver messages to a specific user

Tags: node.js, laravel, socket.io, chat, laravel-9

I have been trying to develop a chat app on Laravel with socket.io. Now, I am facing problem that is when a user is sending a message to a specific user, the message is being delivered to all the available users. May I know the section of code you need to help me out? Or there's some other area where I can specifically look into.

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const server = require('http').createServer(app);

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: { origin: "*" }
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log('Server is running');

   io.on("connection", function(socket) {
       console.log("User" + socket.id);
   
       socket.on("messageSent", function(message, senderId) {
           socket.broadcast.emit("messageSent", message, this.socket.id)
           console.log(this.socket.id);
       });
   
   //msg
       socket.on("msgSent", function(message) {
           socket.broadcast.emit("msgSent", message)
       });
   
   
       socket.on("clientMmsgSent", function(message) {
           socket.broadcast.emit("clientMmsgSent", message)
       });
   });
});
```

Other code:

```
<sc ript>
    var socket = io("{{config('app.server_url')}}");

   function sendMessage(event) {
       $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: {
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
           }
       });
       //console.log('test');
       event.preventDefault();
       if (event.keyCode === 13) {
           var msg = document.getElementById('msg').value;
           var client_id = document.getElementById('client_id').value;
           var operator_id = document.getElementById('operator_id').value;
           //console.log(smg);
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "{{route('send.msg')}}",
               data: {
                   msg: msg,
                   client_id: client_id,
                   operator_id: operator_id,
               },
               beforeSend: function() {

               },
               success: function(data) {
                   var msg = `
                   <div class="operator-msg">
                              ${data.operator_msg}
                           </div>
                   `;
                   
                   console.log(data);
                   socket.emit("msgSent", {
                       'data': data,
                   });
                   $('#opt_msg').append(msg);
               },
               error: function(error) {
                   console.log(error);
               }
           });
           $('#msg').val(" ");
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }
</sc ript>
```

Comment: Your question is too vague for us to answer I think. Without any code sample, we won't be able to help you effectively.

Comment: @ConfusedCopyPaster, I have edited my question with the reference code.

Comment: can you post your code responsible for broadcasting?

Comment: Inserted the other section of the code in the question.